# How can I say 'as is' to make a comparison?

Tags: comparison

I have been wondering how to translate the sentence

> The man is very handsome, as is his brother

to German. Specifically the part I have trouble with is the 'as is'. So far I have written

> (a) 'Der Mann ist sehr gutaussehend, sein Bruder ebenso' or

> (b) 'Der Mann is sehr gutaussehend, ebenso wie sein Bruder'

but I am not sure if either one is totally correct. Should the 'ebenso' be elsewhere?

Thank you very much for your help with this basic question! And apologies if I have made any English mistakes.

Comment: Your translations are both perfectly fine. I just wonder if this is a translation request and you question will be closed soon.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your translations are ok, but the first thing that came to my mind was

> genau wie sein Bruder

This sounds even somewhat more natural and less stilted than "ebenso".

Another alternative would be

> und sein Bruder auch

Comment: Can one say: //Der Mann ist sehr gutaussehend, so ist sein Bruder.// ?

Comment: @KeNSmilePachI: No, because in German, "so" does not have a meaning like "the same way". Your sentence sounds like "The man is handsome, that's the way his brother is." This explicitly excludes any notion of "and" or "too", and therefore sounds as if the speaker were confused about whether they are talking about "the man" or "his brother".

Comment: Thank you very much and I appreciate the suggestions for something that sounds more natural.

Answer (score 4):

Your translation variants are correct. Here are two more suggestions:

> Der Mann ist sehr gutaussehend, so wie sein Bruder.

> Der Mann ist sehr gutaussehend, wie sein Bruder.

Comment: Is "ist" dropped at the end of your second example?? //Der Mann ist sehr gutaussehend, wie sein Bruder ist.//

Comment: @KeNSmilePachI that would be incorrect.

Comment: @KeNSmilePachI Yes, it is omitted.